# How do I copy a list and not share structure?

Tags: common-lisp

Wow, I'm totally not understanding this bit!

I have a list, `L1`. I want to make a copy, `L2` such that, when I modify `L2`, `L1` remains unchanged. I'd-a thought that's what `copy-seq` was for, but it's not behaving as expected.

```
(defun tcopy ()
  (let ((seq1 nil)
        (seq2 nil))
    (setf seq1 (list (list 11 22) (list 33 44 55)))
    (setf seq2 (copy-seq seq1))        
    (format t "before -- s1: ~a s2: ~a~%" seq1 seq2)
    (setf (nth 1 (nth 1 seq2)) 99)
    (format t "after --  s1: ~a s2: ~a~%" seq1 seq2)))
```

And the output:

```
? (tcopy)
before -- s1: ((11 22) (33 44 55)) s2: ((11 22) (33 44 55))
after --  s1: ((11 22) (33 99 55)) s2: ((11 22) (33 99 55)) ; Undesired: s1 is modified
NIL
?
```

I also tried the following:

```
;(setf seq2 (copy-seq seq1))
(setf seq2 (reduce #'cons seg1 :from-end t :initial-value nil))
```

It gives the same results. Lisp-n00b, here; what am I missing?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`COPY-SEQ`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cp_seq.htm#copy-seq) only copies the top-level sequence. Not any subsequences. ([`COPY-LIST`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cp_lis.htm#copy-list) behaves the same way.)

[`COPY-TREE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cp_tre.htm#copy-tree) copies a tree of cons cells. Thus it will also copy lists of lists of lists ...