# Duplicate lists when defining a list of lists in Common Lisp

Tags: compilation, common-lisp, sbcl

I am defining a variable as a list containing lists of symbols:

```
(defparameter *var* '((a a a) (a x a) (a a a)))
```

When I try to change one of the elements with `setf`...

```
(setf (caar *var*) 'c)
```

... both the first *and* the last lists are updated.

```
> *var*
; ((c a a) (a x a) (c a a))
```

I noticed that when I evaluate the `defparameter` in the REPL, the `setf` command works as expected. This makes me think that the unexpected behaviour is related to the compilation process.

Questions:

1. What is happening and why?
2. What would be the canonical way of defining a list of fresh lists containing the same symbols in `defparameter`?

I am using SBCL.

Edit: My question is not similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176711), because I am not asking *how* to copy lists so that they do not share structure, but rather *why* when compiling a `defparameter` lists with similar elements appear to share structure and how to define them so they do not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy a list and not share structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176711/how-do-i-copy-a-list-and-not-share-structure)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I am familiar with `copy-list`, but it doesn't do what I want and is not an answer to my questions. I am asking *why* when compiling a list of similar lists, they share structure (but, for example, when evaluated in the repl they don't.) and how shall I define them such that all lists having the same symbols do not share structure. Thanks

Comment: Attempts to modify list literals or other literal objects lead to [undefined behavior](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ga.htm) in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a frequently asked question.

**Why does SBCL show this implementation dependent behavior?**

Try after loading the compiled file (use `COMPILE-FILE` to compile it):

```
* (eq (first *var*) (third *var*))
T
* *var*
((A A A) (A X A) (A A A))
* (setf *print-circle* t)
T
* *var*
(#1=(A A A) (A X A) #1#)
*
```

Above shows that the first and third sublists are the same.

Running it in the REPL is left as an exercise. It may show different results.

In ANSI Common Lisp the *File Compiler* is allowed to *coalesce* *similar* list data. `(a a a)` and `(a a a)` are similar. This may save memory space in a compiled program. Not every Common Lisp implementation does that, but SBCL does it. Remember, when the book *Common Lisp the Language, 1st edition* was published in 1984, the first Apple Macintosh had just 128KB RAM.

**Solution: use `COPY-TREE`:**

To create a fresh & non coalesced copy of the nested list use the function `COPY-TREE`. *Fresh* means that it is not literal data and thus one is allowed to modify it. `COPY-TREE` copies all levels of a cons tree, `COPY-LIST` only copies the top list. Since your data is nested, we need `COPY-TREE`:

```
(defparameter *var*
  (copy-tree '((a a a) (a x a) (a a a))))
```

Answer (score 4):

When you execute:

```
(setf (caar *var*) 'c)
```

You are relying on undefined behavior, because you are mutating a literal, constant value.  This is explained in the specification of [`QUOTE`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_quote.htm) but the same applies to all literal values:

> The consequences are undefined if literal objects (including quoted objects) are destructively modified.

More generally you have to take care of ownership when deciding if you have the right to mutate or not a list (or any object). If you know that a list was just freshly consed, you can mutate it but sometimes the list is directly given to you and you should refrain from touching it. This is the case for example for `&rest` lists (see [`APPLY`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_apply.htm#apply)):

> conforming programs must neither rely on the list structure of a rest list to be freshly consed

You can often avoid mutations by consing element in front of an existing list (if the list is supposed to be a property list (plist) or an association list (alist)). For example in case your function accepts a keyword argument named `a`:

```
(defun foo (&key a) (list a))
```

Then you can call it with as many `:a` as you want, only the first is taken into account:

```
(foo :a 3 :a 2 :a 1)
=> (3)

(apply 'foo (list :a 3 :a 2 :a 1))
=> (3)
```

But in cases where you do want to change the list significantly, you must use functions that produce a fresh copy (like `remove` or `copy-list`).